# Question about the proof that there does not exist a fine moduli space for endomorphisms of $n$-dimensional vector spaces.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

I am reading Mumford's 1970 Oslo lecture on moduli theory.

In this lecture, he defines a family of n-dimensional vector space endomorphisms over a scheme $T$ to be a pair $(\mathcal{E}, \phi)$ where $\mathcal{E}$ is a rank $n$ vector bundle over $T$ and $\phi$ is a vector bundle endomorphism of $\mathcal{E}$.

The proof that there exists n fine moduli space $M$ representing such families is quite short: Namely, let $(\mathcal{E}, \phi)$ be any such family over a scheme $T$, then for any non-trivial line bundle $L$ on $T$, the pair $(\mathcal{E} \otimes L, \phi \otimes 1_L)$ and $(\mathcal{E}, \phi)$ determine the same morphism $T \to M$.

Why do $(\mathcal{E}, \phi)$ and $(\mathcal{E} \otimes L, \phi \otimes 1_L)$ determine the same morphism $T \to M$?

Comment: Maybe there needs to be more context here? Try considering the identity map $id:M \to M$. This is (by the fine moduli property) induced by the universal rank $n$ bundle $\mathcal E \to M$ and a universal endomorphism $\phi$. Now if I pick a line bundle $L \not\cong \mathcal O_M$, then $\mathcal E\otimes L \not\cong \mathcal E$. On the other hand, the tensor product $\phi\otimes 1_L$ should "look the same as $\phi$" on each fiber since in a trivialization $1_L$ is just the $1\times 1$ identity matrix, so it *should* induce the same map. If you can make that precise, you should be done.

Comment: Oh hmm, I guess the logic is that Zariski locally on T, any line bundle is trivial, and so the map T to M is Zariski locally the same. If $M$ were a fine moduli space, (so in particular a sheaf) then the map to $M$ determined by $(I_n, \phi)$ would have to be the same as the map determined by $(\mathcal{E} \otimes L, \phi \otimes 1_L)$. But obv. these two pairs are not isomorphic so should not correspond to the same map.